# The victims or victims?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

Why is it "the victims" in this sentence?

> "Mr. Trump stated, "Without looking at the various polling data, it is
>   obvious to anybody the hatred is beyond comprehension. Where this
>   hatred comes from and why we will have to determine. Until we are able
>   to determine and understand this problem and the dangerous threat it
>   poses, our country cannot be **the victims** of horrendous attacks by
>   people that believe only in Jihad, and have no sense of reason or
>   respect for human life. If I win the election for President, we are
>   going to Make America Great Again."

Could we omit the article there? What warrants the definite article to be there exactly?

Comment: When there is OF after a noun, the rule is: the [noun] of [noun]. **The** offices **of** companies in overseas locations. **The** style of **writers** in Latin America, etc. That said /the victims of horrendous attacks/ means something slightly different than /victims of horrendous attacks/.

Answer (score 1):

The plural without an article is a form of generalization, and so without **the** the idea is expressed in rather abstract terms.

> We cannot allow ourselves to become victims of X ...

With **the**, the expression is made more "concrete" and particular, just a little more real.

This fine a shade of difference only comes to the fore when the text is subjected to a kind of close-up analysis that most listeners never engage in. The subconscious effects, however, are probably measurable; you could strap focus groups to wiring harnesses and measure their heartbeat, respiration, body temperature, eye dilation, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The cited context is inherently "flawed, awkward", since it's using the copula form ***[cannot] be*** to link singular ***our country*** and plural ***[the] victims***. But we could resolve that with, say,...

> *We cannot be [the] victims of our circumstances.*

...where *grammatically / syntactically* the article ***the*** is entirely optional. *Statistically*, it's not likely to be included, as can be seen by comparing the non-negated forms [*We are victims of circumstance*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we%20are%20victims%20of%20circumstance%22) (229 hits in Google Books) and [*We are **the** victims of circumstance*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we%20are%20victims%20of%20circumstance%22#tbm=bks&q=%22we%20are%20the%20victims%20of%20circumstance%22) (6 hits).

---

But *semantically* there's at least a potential difference in emphasis, in that including the article implies that ***the*** victims do actually exist (logically extrapolated from the principle that the definite article references something previously mentioned or contextually obvious).

A pedant might therefore suggest that Trump's inclusion of ***the*** implies that he accepts there *are/will be* victims of horrendous attacks (he just doesn't want *Americans* to be those<sup>1</sup> victims).

A politically-motivated pedant might therefore go on to suggest Trump's choice of phrase here reflects an "isolationist" world-view (Trump wants to ensure *America* isn't a victim, rather than to prevent all such horrendous attacks worldwide, and thereby ensure *no-one* is a victim).

That's just clutching at straws, though. Both versions are fine, and to all intents and purposes they both mean the same thing.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that my ***those*** is a "determiner" with exactly the same implications as ***the*** in respect of the "referent does actually exist" argument here.